# Error retrieving state map in kerberized cluster

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

HDP-2.5.3.0.

A custom processor uses the State api to persist some data.

```
try {
stateMap = stateManager.getState(Scope.CLUSTER);
stateMapProperties = new HashMap<>(stateMap.toMap());
logger.debug("Retrieved the statemap : " + stateMapProperties);
...

...

...
} catch (IOException ioe) {
logger.error("Couldn't load the state map", ioe);
throw new ProcessException(ioe);
}
```

The processor works fine on my local machine's NiFi but when I put it on our (kerberized)dev cluster which has 2 NiFi nodes, it fails with the following error(Exception) :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain value from ZooKeeper for component with ID d7fff389-015a-1000-ffff-ffffd04d1279 with exception code NOAUTH
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider.getState(ZooKeeperStateProvider.java:420) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.StandardStateManager.getState(StandardStateManager.java:63) ~[na:na]
at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.getDataFromChangeTables(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:480) [nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.onTrigger(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:191) [nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /nifi/components/d7fff389-015a-1000-ffff-ffffd04d1279
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:113) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1184) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider.getState(ZooKeeperStateProvider.java:403) ~[na:na]
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain value from ZooKeeper for component with ID d7fff389-015a-1000-ffff-ffffd04d1279 with exception code NOAUTH
at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.getDataFromChangeTables(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:493) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.onTrigger(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:191) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain value from ZooKeeper for component with ID d7fff389-015a-1000-ffff-ffffd04d1279 with exception code NOAUTH
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider.getState(ZooKeeperStateProvider.java:420) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.StandardStateManager.getState(StandardStateManager.java:63) ~[na:na]
at com.datalake.processors.SQLServerCDCProcessor.getDataFromChangeTables(SQLServerCDCProcessor.java:480) ~[nifi-NiFiCDCPoC-processors-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /nifi/components/d7fff389-015a-1000-ffff-ffffd04d1279
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:113) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1184) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider.getState(ZooKeeperStateProvider.java:403) ~[na:na]
... 15 common frames omitted
```

Following are the entries in the state-management.xml

```
<cluster-provider>
        <id>zk-provider</id>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider</class>
        <property name="Connect String">l4373t.sss.se.scania.com:2181,l4283t.sss.se.scania.com:2181,l4284t.sss.se.scania.com:2181</property>
        <property name="Root Node">/nifi</property>
        <property name="Session Timeout">10 seconds</property>
        <property name="Access Control">CreatorOnly</property>
    </cluster-provider>
```

Any ideas ?

*****Edit-1*****
Adding the zk jaas configuration.

```
bash-4.2$ cat zookeeper-jaas.conf
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="/usr/local/nifi/keys/nifi_l4513t.sss.se.com.keytab"
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=true
  principal="nifi/l4513t.sss.se.com@GLOBAL.SCD.COM";
};
```

The entry(as 'java.arg.16') in the bootstrap.conf file :

```
bash-4.2$ vi bootstrap.conf
#

# Java command to use when running NiFi
java=java

# Username to use when running NiFi. This value will be ignored on Windows.
run.as=

# Configure where NiFi's lib and conf directories live
lib.dir=./lib
conf.dir=./conf

# How long to wait after telling NiFi to shutdown before explicitly killing the Process
graceful.shutdown.seconds=20

# Disable JSR 199 so that we can use JSP's without running a JDK
java.arg.1=-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true

# JVM memory settings
java.arg.2=-Xms1024m
java.arg.3=-Xmx2048m

# Enable Remote Debugging
#java.arg.debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

java.arg.4=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

# allowRestrictedHeaders is required for Cluster/Node communications to work properly
java.arg.5=-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
java.arg.6=-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol

java.arg.7=-Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=/var/log/nifi

# The G1GC is still considered experimental but has proven to be very advantageous in providing great
# performance without significant "stop-the-world" delays.
java.arg.13=-XX:+UseG1GC

#Set headless mode by default
java.arg.14=-Djava.awt.headless=true

java.arg.15=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/local/nifi/conf/kafka-jaas.conf
java.arg.16=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/local/nifi/conf/zookeeper-jaas.conf
# Master key in hexadecimal format for encrypted sensitive configuration values
nifi.bootstrap.sensitive.key=

###
# Notification Services for notifying interested parties when NiFi is stopped, started, dies
###
```

*****Edit-2***** Providing the existing kafka-jaas.conf

```
bash-4.2$ cat kafka-jaas.conf
KafkaServer {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   storeKey=true
   renewTicket=true
   useTicketCache=true
   serviceName="kafka"
   keyTab="/usr/local/nifi/keys/nifi_l4513t.sss.se.com.keytab"
   principal="nifi/l4513t.sss.se.com@GLOBAL.SCD.COM";
};
KafkaClient {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   useTicketCache=true
   renewTicket=true
   serviceName="kafka"
   keyTab="/usr/local/nifi/keys/nifi_l4513t.sss.se.com.keytab"
   principal="nifi/l4513t.sss.se.com@GLOBAL.SCD.COM";
};
Client {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   storeKey=true
   useTicketCache=true
   serviceName="kafka"
   keyTab="/usr/local/nifi/keys/nifi_l4513t.sss.se.com.keytab"
   principal="nifi/l4513t.sss.se.com@GLOBAL.SCD.COM";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking to a Kerberized ZooKeeper then there is additional config required beyond the state-management.xml. Take a look at the Admin Guide section on securing ZooKeeper, specifically the section "Kerberizing NiFi's ZooKeeper Client":

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#zk_kerberos_client

EDIT:

This article shows an example of the different JAAS scenarios:

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/28180/how-to-configure-hdf-12-to-send-to-and-get-data-fr.html

Most of the examples in article use an embedded ZK, so taking that out I think you would need something like:

```
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="./conf/nifi.keytab"
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=false
  principal="nifi@EXAMPLE.COM”;
};

KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=true
  renewTicket=true
  serviceName="kafka"
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="./conf/nifi.keytab"
  principal="nifi@EXAMPLE.COM";
};
```

Comment: I looked at that section and made the changes, still the error persists. Editing the original question to include the changes.

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist Ok I'm not sure if you can have two JAAS files specified (Kafka and ZK), I think you might need to create a single file with both entries in it and then specify only that one file in bootstrap.conf

Comment: If that doesn't work you may want to enable Kerberos debugging...
java.arg.17=-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true and see what prints out in nifi-boostrap.log when you see the error in the processor.

Comment: The kafka-jaas.conf has a 'Client' entry already, how should I position the new entry for ZK ? Another part that intrigues me is the 'KafkaClient' entry which has 'serviceName="kafka"', is it something that is missing in the zookeeper-jaas.conf ?

Comment: Since NiFi is a client of Kafka and ZK here, I don't think you need the KafkaServer entry in the JAAS file. The "serviceName" entry is specific to Kafka, the Kafka client is looking for this and the Kafka processors have a field where you enter the service name which has to match what is in the JAAS file.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need another Client entry... if you are going to use the same principal (nifi/l4513t.sss.se.com@GLOBAL.SCD.COM) to talk to ZK, then I think the client entry that is already there would work.

Comment: In case both Kafka and ZK are to be served using the same file, can you give an idea about how the final ?-jaas.conf should look ?

Comment: Yes I tried to edit the answer with what I think you would need.